# Existence of an eigenpair for d-bar operator in the unit disck

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, sp.spectral-theory, analytic-functions

Let $\overline{\partial}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{x}+\textrm{i} \,\partial_y)$ and let $D$ be the unit disc in the complex plane. For each $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, consider the problem:
$$ \overline{\partial} \phi = \lambda\, \phi \quad \text{on $D$},$$
subject to the boundary condition $\textrm{Re}(\phi) =0$ on $\partial D$.

Does  there exist a nontrivial pair $(\phi,\lambda)$?

Answer (score -1):

For each $\lambda$,the solution is of the form
$\phi(z)=h(z)\exp(\lambda \overline{z}+\overline{\lambda} z)$
where h is holomorphic and purely imaginary along the boundary.

For $\psi(z):=\exp(-\lambda\overline{z})\phi(z)$ is holomorphic by the PDE and subject to boundary condition
$$
\exp(\lambda\overline{z})\psi(z)=-\exp(\overline{\lambda}z)\overline{\psi(z)}
$$
thus $\exp(-\overline{\lambda} z)\psi(z)$ is holomorphic with boundary value being pure imaginary.